# __exit__ swallowing TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I was reminding myself about the ''keyword'' and I stumbled across this article http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm. I just had a small, likely obvious, question. The article states that this ''swallows any TypeError''

```
 def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    return isinstance(value, TypeError)
```

I'm not quite seeing how that is the case? A quick explanation would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: [The documentation for `__exit__` mentions this.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you return `True` from an `__exit__` clause, it will stop any errors from going through. For example:

```
class Foo():
    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter")
    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        print("exit with", repr(value))
        return True

with Foo():
    print("inside")
    raise ValueError()
```

will output

```
enter
inside
exit with ValueError()
```

but not raise anything because `__exit__()` returned `True`.

In the example case, if the error raised is a `TypeError`, the statement:

```
return isinstance(value, TypeError)
```

Will return `True` and the `TypeError` will be "swallowed".